# Visual Studio Code: "Open Recent" does not have a file I opened in last session

Tags: visual-studio-code

I feel like a fool posting this.

I am on 1.40.1 of VS Code. I have observed this problem for a year or more now, across many updates.

1. Clean boot,
2. Open VS Code
3. In VS Code, open file: c:\temp\1.txt
4. Close c:\temp\1.txt
5. Exit VS Code
6. Open VS Code
7. Go to Open Recent
8. Files from months ago are there, but 1.txt is NOT THERE  **<--- This is the
   issue!**

How to resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a closed issue (#66349) that seems identical to the behavior you describe:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66349

Here is the explanation of the UI and suggested workaround:

> That list is populated from opening something into VSCode from outside (e.g. via command line or File > open). It is not meant to change whenever you open an editor from within. In that case Ctrl+P is the best way to open recently opened files.

Issue (#66349) was merged into this closed issue, which has a wholly unsatisfying conclusion:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/57642

> This issue is being closed to keep the number of issues in our inbox on a manageable level, we are closing issues that are not going to be addressed in the foreseeable future: We look at the number of votes the issue has received and the number of duplicate issues filed. More details here. If you disagree and feel that this issue is crucial: We are happy to listen and to reconsider.

So the resolution for the now is to rely on `Ctrl + P` instead of the Open Recent list.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, those issues are what I describe. The VSCode gui is simply broken in this area (File menu has "Open Recent" , Ctrl-P gives a list of "Recently Opened" ... some ux god is asleep....). Bummer for all of us to have the gui drifting like this.

Comment: Time to open a new issue, it seems, called: "Open Recent is Confusingly Similar to Recently Opened"

Comment: @DylanKinnett Great idea! Done!  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116066

Comment: @JonesomeReinstateMonica Progress! Now it says "This feature request is now a candidate for our backlog. The community has 60 days to upvote the issue. If it receives 20 upvotes we will move it to our backlog. If not, we will close it."

Comment: @DylanKinnett Yup, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/116044 is live...  FWIW , I opened this issue up a couple of years ago, and it was killed. I have observed that FOSS projects often lack sufficient "GUI dictator" leadership. (Because any change made at this point will upset some people, so messy GUI decisions tend to proliferate over time.)

Comment: I still cannot see "Opened Folders" with Ctrl/CMD+P. Is this just me? It must be that this command is not supposed to check for folders, but ctrl+R does. It should not have been this hard tbh.